# Where to find Openldap Cisco Anyconnect schema?

Tags: linux, openldap, anyconnect

How do I find the `cisco.schema` schema file in a Debian Jessie system?
Which packages I do need to install?

Ideally with a readme file for the schema as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Cisco Anyconnect documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/lightweight-directory-access-protocol-ldap/116096-configure-anyconnect-openldap-00.html) you need to manually create the file. The documentation contains `cisco.schema` listing:

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.1
  NAME 'CiscoBanner'
  DESC 'Banner Name for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.2
  NAME 'CiscoACLin'
  DESC 'ACL in for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.3
  NAME 'CiscoDomain'
  DESC 'Domain for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.4
  NAME 'CiscoDNS'
  DESC 'DNS server for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.5
  NAME 'CiscoIPAddress'
  DESC 'Address for VPN user'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.6
  NAME 'CiscoIPNetmask'
  DESC 'Address for VPN user'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.7
  NAME 'CiscoSplitACL'
  DESC 'Split tunnel list for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.8
  NAME 'CiscoSplitTunnelPolicy'
  DESC 'Split tunnel policy for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.1.9
  NAME 'CiscoGroupPolicy'
  DESC 'Group policy for VPN users'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{128}
  SINGLE-VALUE )

objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.500.2.1 NAME 'CiscoPerson'
        DESC 'My cisco person'
        AUXILIARY
        MUST ( sn $ cn )
        MAY ( userPassword $ telephoneNumber $ seeAlso
            $ description $ CiscoBanner $ CiscoACLin $ CiscoDomain
            $ CiscoDNS $ CiscoIPAddress $ CiscoIPNetmask $ CiscoSplitACL
            $ CiscoSplitTunnelPolicy $ CiscoGroupPolicy ) )
```